# how does foldr workk in this situation?

Tags: list, haskell, fold

i have this function that counts the number of occurences of n in a list:

`count n = foldr (\x acc -> if n == x then acc+1 else acc) 0`

now if i do

```
> count 2 [2,2,3,2,2]
> 4
```

what i don't understand is why i can't do the following instead
which i find far more easier to read

`count n [x:xs] = foldr (\x acc -> if n == x then acc+1 else acc) 0 [x:xs]`

count takes two arguments, but why when defining the function i dont explicitily write out the second argument (the list argument) where does it go?

Comment: Let's formulate Basic Statement One. If you can write `anythingAtAll x = somethingElse x`,  then you can also write `anythingAtAll = somethingElse`. It doesn't matter what `anythingAtAll` and `somethingElse` are. Do you have a problem with this statement?

Comment: Aside: where you write `[x:xs]` I assume you mean `(x:xs)`.

Comment: Other than that, you ask "why I can't do..." - but in fact you can. What you write (with the correction I noted) is completely equivalent to the original, and some will prefer writing it that way. (I prefer to "eliminate" the common argument, but it's largely a matter of taste.)

Comment: The `[x:xs]` pattern matches a singleton list, it is short for `[(x:xs)]`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond oh so basically you can eliminate the common argument? that was really my problem, it really confuses me haha but i think i see it now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[x:xs]` pattern is short for `[(x:xs)]`, which means a *singleton* list (a list with one element) that matches the `(x:xs)` pattern.

The `(x:xs)` pattern is a *non-empty* list. Indeed, here `x` is the *head* (the first element), and `xs` the *tail* (the list with the remaining elements). The pattern for an empty list is `[]`. If you thus would write:

```
-- does not work with empty lists
count n (x:xs) = foldr (\x acc -> if n == x then acc+1 else acc) 0 (x:xs)
```

It means it will not "*fire*" for an empty list. You can however make use of a parameter:

```
count n xs = foldr (\x acc -> if n == x then acc+1 else acc) 0 xs
```

This is a variable that will match with any value, so both empty and non-empty lists.